# Getting module route import paths in Play

Tags: routes, module, playframework

If I have a typical entry in my routes file for importing routes from a module

```
*       /admin                  module:crud
```

is there a way for me to determine that the base path for the `crud` module is `/admin`, other than just parsing the main routes file myself?  It doesn't appear that the `Router` class keeps this information.

The ultimate goal is to create a menu for each module.  If I have a user management module imported at `/useradmin`, I want to generate a menu containing `/useradmin/users` and `/useradmin/groups` but not deeper descendants such as `/useradmin/users/new`.  If `/useradmin` is routed to something, I'll use that as the link for the menu's label, otherwise I'll just show a plain text label.

While I might be able to fake it without knowing, it seems like knowing the actual base url for the module would be the best way to ensure I can handle various special cases such as modules imported at `/modules/useradmin` or modules that grandchild paths but no child paths (`/useradmin/users/new` but no `/useradmin/users`).

Answer (score 2):

the question is: why do you need to parse the file or know that '/admin' is the base? Play allows you to use [reverse routing](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/routes#reverse) to get the path.

From the link above:

*For example, with this route definition:*

```
GET    /clients/{id}      Clients.show
```

*From your code, you can generate the URL able to invoke Clients.show:*

```
map.put("id", 1541);
String url = Router.reverse("Clients.show", map).url;  // GET /clients/1541
```

That should be enough.

Comment: For most cases you'd be right, but I think I've got a legit reason for wanting to know.  I'm working on a module that generates menubars and breadcrumbs of where you've been.  Currently the best way to generate a menu for a module seems to be to determine where the module "starts" in the path, and then look for routable paths one level below that.

Comment: @Bemace could you explain with more detail the functionality you want to generate? I'm not sure I understand it (adding this to the question would help)

Answer (score 1):

Just now, I don't see anything else than parsing the route yourself.
Look at the play.mvc.Router class IMO and following function :

```
static void parse(VirtualFile routeFile, String prefix) {
    String fileAbsolutePath = routeFile.getRealFile().getAbsolutePath();
    int lineNumber = 0;
    String content = routeFile.contentAsString();
    if (content.indexOf("${") > -1 || content.indexOf("#{") > -1 || content.indexOf("%{") > -1) {
        // Mutable map needs to be passed in.
        content = TemplateLoader.load(routeFile).render(new HashMap<String, Object>(16));
    }
    for (String line : content.split("\n")) {
        lineNumber++;
        line = line.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        if (line.length() == 0 || line.startsWith("#")) {
            continue;
        }
        Matcher matcher = routePattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String action = matcher.group("action");
            // module:
            if (action.startsWith("module:")) {
                String moduleName = action.substring("module:".length());
                String newPrefix = prefix + matcher.group("path");
                ...
```

It extracts the prefix which is the part you look for.